# Array.Push overwrites the previous Value Node Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, push

Good day.
I have an global array and it **MUST** be global.

```
var comments= [];
```

I have an callback of a socket where i am iterating through it and adding the values.

Better with the code :

```
    socket.on('commentAdded', function (data) {
    if (data !== null) {
        var stringify = JSON.stringify(data);
        var json = JSON.parse(stringify);

        Object.keys(users).forEach(function (key) {
            if (key !== "null") {
                data.eachUserId = key;
                console.log("data added with id " + key + " the size of comments is " + comments.size);
                comments.push(data);
            }
        });
        console.log("comment was added");
    }

    socket.broadcast.emit('onCommentAdded', data);
});
```

Here my `console.Log("data added with id)...` is printing everything correctly and ideally i want to add a new value to the **existing data which is a json data** and the name of a new value is `eachUserId` which value must be fully different as i am doing it inside the loop as you can see.

And here is how i get the items afterwards.

```
   for (var f = 0; f < Object.keys(comments).length; f++) {
        var comment = comments[f];
        var eachUserId = comment.eachUserId;
        console.log("checking with current user id" + userId + " each user id" + eachUserId + " or each user id in [] way " + comment['eachUserId']);
        if (eachUserId === userId) {
            socket.emit('onCommentAdded', comment);
        }
    }
```

Here the **eachUserId** is always the very last item which was added in loop... what am i doing wrong? Why the `push()` method overwrite every value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:**

You problem is when you assign the value to `eachUserId` to object `data`. You have only 1 object named `data` and you are adding this same object into the array over and over again. But remember they all refer to the same object, and when you'll change anything in that object *it'll reflect everywhere*.

So, when you change `data.eachUserId = key;` in loop, it changes for all items in array. And at the end all of them contains the last `eachUserId` value you assigned to it.

**Solution:**

You need to clone the object, and then push it into the array.

---

I will suggest you to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) library and [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep) method to create a deep clone of your object.

```
var _ = require('lodash');  //require "lodash"

socket.on('commentAdded', function (data) {
    if (data !== null) {        
        Object.keys(users).forEach(function (key) {
            if (key !== "null") {
                var dataClone = _.cloneDeep(data);  //create deep clone
                dataClone.eachUserId = key;         //assign "key"
                comments.push(dataClone);           //push into the array
            }
        });
        console.log("comment was added");
    }    
    socket.broadcast.emit('onCommentAdded', data);
});
```

Comment: Amazing! The best solution and it has worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use Spread Operator, it is already Stage 4 ([ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread))

```js
const foo = {}

const bar = {...foo}

foo.a = 1;
bar.a = 10;

console.log(foo) // {a : 1}
console.log(bar) // {a : 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `comments` is containing the required data. Wrap  it inside a `closure`, so it creates a `new scope for each iteration` and passes the right data.

```
for (var f = 0; f < Object.keys(comments).length; f++) {
       (function(f){
          var comment = comments[f];
          var eachUserId = comment.eachUserId;
          console.log("checking with current user id" + userId + " each user id" + eachUserId + " or each user id in [] way " + comment['eachUserId']);
          if (eachUserId === userId) {
             socket.emit('onCommentAdded', comment);
          }
       )(f))
    }
```

Comment: this is not what i want...i just wanted to add a data to existing json object and insert it into the array,this is not resolving my issue